# Shared Preferences returns null on startup when fetching Firebase user ID in Flutter

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I am fetching my user's ID when the user logs in, and storing it in Shared Preferences in my Login Page, like so

```
 Future<FirebaseUser> _register() async {

// ... Firebase Login Code

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 if (user != null) {
          // Check is already sign up
          final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .where('id', isEqualTo: user.uid)
              .getDocuments();
          final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
          if (documents.length == 0) {
            // Update data to server if new user
            Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).setData({
              'id': user.uid,
              'name': user.displayName
            });
            currentUser = user;
            await prefs.setString('id', currentUser.uid);
            await prefs.setString('name', currentUser.displayName);
          } else {
            await prefs.setString('id', documents[0]['id']);
            await prefs.setString('name', documents[0], ['name']);
          }
        }
```

}

I then pass the user to my home screen, if the user isn't null, after the user enters the homepage, the user ID received by shared prefs is null, 
I am fetching the user's ID from the initState()

```
void initState() {
fetchName();
}

fetchName() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      userTestName = prefs.getString('name') ?? '';
    id = prefs.getString('id') ?? '';

    }
```

Problem #1
After I shut the app & restart it, my user ID is retrieved and I can display my user's name however I can't achieve this the first time the user logs in the app.

Problem #2
If I log out my user, and log the user back in the ID stored in shared prefs is still the previous value which when logged in, calls the old user's ID and then when the app is relaunched fetches the new user's ID.

I tried looking on other Stack Overflow pages but I am still pretty confused & new to Flutter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why use SharedPreferences** **while working with Firebase ??**
when you can directly access the logged in user details from **FirebaseAuth** object when your app starts.

```
    FirebaseUser loggedUser;
    checkLoggedIn() {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
          if (user != null ) {
             loggedUser = user;
             setState(() {});
             // all these values may or may not be null that depends if the user's 
             // login provider has got these details from user or not
             //user.providerId;// access the logged in userId
             //user.displayName;// access logged in user Name
             //user.email;// access logged in user email
             //user.phoneNumber;// access logged in user contact number 
          }
        });
      }
```

call **checkLoggedIn()** method **inside initState()** function of a stateful widget

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkLoggedIn();
  }
```

Comment: How do I get the users uid in the homepage after I check if they are logged in or not? I need to fetch the users Firestore data like  for e.f their display name in the home page.

Comment: use the same object in the homepage, FirebaseAuth object to get the currently logged in user. or u can just simply make the FirebaseUser loggenIn object outside StatefulWidget in ur main class so u can use it in every other class which wont be the most secure way of doing that. one more way you can pass the FirebaseUser object along to the homepage class as a parameter and  use that object directly inside Homepage